# grails to build Web interface using REST API

Tags: json, rest, grails

I am fairly new to Grails, and I have a few questions on how to proceed.

I have a REST API which I will use to retrieve the data , for exemple :

```
http://localhost/api/data/list
```

Which gives this result :

```
{"data":[{"col1":"blabla","col2":0},{"col1":"moreblabla","col2":1}]}
```

I want to use Grails to build an interface for those data (show, edit, add, delete)

Should I create a domain called Data ?

How do I tell Grails to to use the REST API and not a database ?

I am really clueless so I hope you can light the way ;)

Thank you.

Comment: What data are you requesting restfully? Rest is a way of calling/retrieving/communicating. It doesn't really have much to do with the database, but grails allows you to create rest services that read/and write database as your persistent store on the backend.

You can create custom mappings, defined at http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/URL%20mappings.html that won't bind you to choosing 'api' and 'data' for your domains, although you're more than welcome to do that if you'd like (and it makes sense).

Comment: Well you can use grails to build the rest API - however to build the user interface on that api isnt specific to grails, you can use any other frameworks (including grails) to create the user interface - look at some javascript frameworks as well, like backbone.js etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails currently doesn't have a GORM plugin for using a REST endpoint as a persistence store. [That is planned functionality, but is not slated to land until later this year](http://grails.org/Roadmap) (2012 - Q4).

That being said, you can write a service that will allow you to do basic CRUD operations on an object and get/persist to and from your REST endpoint. The place to start with that is the [HttpBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/HTTP+Builder), and perhaps the [REST client plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rest).